# I want to install nodejs with latest version

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-18.04, nvm

Currently, I have node version 10.10.0. I want to install it with the latest version. On my ubuntu 18.4 LTS bionic.

I tried using

1. `url -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -`
2. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
3. `node -v`

but it still shows the older version

I have also tried

1. `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash`
2. `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
3. `nvm install 12.12.0`

these steps show 12.12.0 version on `node -v` command, but when I open a new terminal or virtual environment it again shows the older version which is 10.10.0. Please provide a solution.

Comment: Try set default version for nvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a node version manager and set the default node version. Use below command to set the default version.

```
nvm alias default <version>
e.g nvm alias default 12.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nvm use 12` to make the terminal recognize which version you want to use

Comment: Hey thank you for feedback. I have tried it earlier also, It works fine for the current terminal but when i open new terminal and check node version it is showing me older version.

Answer (score 0):

I just did `pip3 install npm`.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a brand new ubuntu 16.04 64-bit on my VirtualBox. Here is what I did to install latest version nodejs:

1. go to https://nodejs.org/, click on 12.16.1 LTS, which is the latest version I could get. download will be initiated in a few seconds
2. create a folder for nodejs(if not exist):

```
    sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/nodejs
```

3. uzip to the folder just created:

```
    sudo tar -xJvf node-v12.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz -C /usr/local/lib/nodejs
```

4. set the environment variable `~/.profile`, add below to the end of the file(make sure you don't have duplicate in this file)

```
    # Nodejs
    VERSION=v10.15.0
    DISTRO=linux-x64
    export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin:$PATH
```

5. refresh the profile

```
    . ~/.profile
```

Congratulations! Now if you issue `node -v`, you should get `v12.16.1`.

This may not be the optimal way to update the nodejs if you currently have one previous version installed, but it can let you choose which one to keep (by modifying the PATH, another file you may want to touch is `/etc/profile`).

I also suggest you uninstall current nodejs (e.g. `sudo apt-get purge node`) before proceed to install the lastest one.

Reference:

[Installation - nodejs help page on github](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation)